# Can't find password in AWS System Log for new AMI created from Bitnami Wordpress AMI

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I created an EC2 instance using the Bitnami Wordpress AMI found in the marketplace.  Then because I wanted to change which AZ it was in, I stopped the instance and created an AMI from that instance. Then I launched the new instance based on the new AMI.  When I went to look for the password in the System log there was nothing to be found. I'm assuming because it was now launching from a new image that I created and not the original Bitnami image. Where can I find the password now to access my Wordpress website?  Anything different that I should have done?

Comment: Are you not able to use the old UN and password? And also just to be clear you want the Wordpress Dashboards UN and Password correct?

Comment: Did you read this link for password did any of that work https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/cloud/aws

Answer (score 4):

I was working with one of these instances and figured out that the log will not display in your Amazon console for whatever reason. You have to first make sure that you have `chmod 400 wordpress.pem` to set your permissions on your key so the instance accepts it when you attempt to ssh. Then ssh in. Then you have to go check the log in `/var/log/boot.log` to find the password for the Wordpress site.

Comment: On mine it ended up being exactly these steps, except at the end it was /var/log/syslog - not boot.log - not sure why the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Wordpress, as with most AMIs, disables password-based login over SSH. Instead, you need to connect to the EC2 Instance using the private key that corresponds to the "EC2 Key Pair" that you selected when you launched the new EC2 Instance.

If you're on a Mac or Linux box, you can connect with a bash command like:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key.pem bitnami@<server-ip>
```

Also, make sure your EC2 Instance's Security Group allows SSH from your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the server using `ssh <credentials>`.
2. Use`$ cat bitnami_credentials` command in command prompt/terminal. It will show you both your username and password.